# R - Concisely add vector to each vector element

Tags: r, vector

Let's say I have a simple vector

```
v <- 1:5
```

I can add the vector to each element within the vector with the following code to generate the resulting matrix.

```
matrix(rep(v, 5), nrow=5, byrow=T) + matrix(rep(v, 5), nrow=5)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    3    4    5    6    7
[3,]    4    5    6    7    8
[4,]    5    6    7    8    9
[5,]    6    7    8    9   10
```

But this seems verbose and inefficient.  Is there a more concise way to accomplish this?  Perhaps some linear algebra concept that is evading me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`outer` should do what you want

```
outer(v, v, `+`)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    2    3    4    5    6
# [2,]    3    4    5    6    7
# [3,]    4    5    6    7    8
# [4,]    5    6    7    8    9
# [5,]    6    7    8    9   10
```

Comment: Nice, do you know how the internals of this function work though?  I'm curious how this `outer sum` is accomplished.

Comment: @cdeterman - the source code for the function is pretty simple.  Type `outer` into the console

Comment: was just about to say the same thing, it's really a convenience function

Comment: Similarly, `sapply(v,"+",v)`

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer not for up votes but to highlight Franks comment. You can use

```
sapply(v,"+",v)
```

Comment: Although this looks nice but this will be probably inefficient compared to the vectorized `outer`. Also, when posting some elses comment "not for votes" as you say, it is better to make it community wiki.